# Polygon pour error in Altium

Tags: altium, eda

I am using Altium (Ver 14). I designed the board and all seemed fine. But, when I edited the same PCB today, it behaves funny.
I have quite a few polygons on my PCB. Previously the polygon would connect to the relevant nets and nothing else. But now, when I edit the polygons, they merge with almost everything and not just the net that it should pour over.
I am attaching a screen shot.
I am also attaching the polygon properties. The type of polygon is the "Pour over same net objects". So, it should not pour of all and sundry.

Can anyone help me on this please ?

[image: The polyon which pours over all !!!!]

[image: The properties tab of the said polygon.]

[image: Rules screen shot.]

Comment: This might be a dumb suggestion, but have you tried repouring all polygons? Hotkey is t -> g -> up arrow (x3) -> enter :)

Comment: yes tried that as well. No luck. I am now thinking if design rules is the culprit. I will update a screen shot.

Comment: How do I give clearance rules for polygon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed the rules. I had not givn a clearance rule specified between 2 nets. When this rule was specified all fell in place.